# Group totals in tablix - only returning first value

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have a tablix that is grouped (row group) according to variety name, and year planted.

Itemized, each plot has an area, and without grouping, this is showing up correctly in the report.  With grouping, per variety name and year planted, it only returns the first value, rather than the total of all values within the groups.

I've tried Fields!NewArea.Value, and SUM(Fields!NewArea.Value) - it still returns on the first record's area, rather than the sum areas.

Can someone tell me how to achieve the sum, per group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you right-click on your rowgroup in the grouping pane below the main design window, then choose Add Total Before/After. It should create sums in the new total row automatically, but if not then the expression just needs to be

```
=SUM(Fields!myFieldName.Value)
```

The SUM() is evaluated at the row context level, so in your case it will be the sum of the values in the same row group.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried the =Sum( formula - it's not summarizing the values it just returns the first value.  If I have two row, with the same variety and year, and each one is 2.5, with grouping on the row and with =sum(, I should have 5.  But instead, I only have 2.5 .  Removing grouping correctly itemizes it, but I can't get the sum.

Comment: edit your question and show a screenshot of your report design. Click the cell where the expression is before you do the screen shot and make sure to show the row group pane. This will help highlight which rowgroup it belongs to. Also show a screenshot of the rowgroup's group properties. This kind of thing is normally very very simple, so I suspect there is something in the design that's been changed from the typical or default structure.

Comment: Hi Alan, thank you for your help. I rebuilt the report, to make it as simple as possible and the formula did work.  So you were right, something happened with the design of the report.